# Renaming associations in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Reminder < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :offices, class_name: :failed_offices
end

class Office < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :reminders
end

class OfficesReminder < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :office
    belongs_to :reminder
end
```

If I do this in rails console I am getting an error

```
p=Reminder.last
p.failed_offices
```

undefined method `failed_offices' for Reminder:0x00007ff87014df78
I want to rename the association for offices. So I tried failed_offices as class_name in Reminder class but it didn't do the trick. Please suggest how it is possible.

Comment: 1. You have it backwards -- it needs to be `has_and_belongs_to_many :failed_offices, class_name: 'Office'`

Comment: 2. Out of context... What is a **failed** office?! I don't understand what that could mean, and there's no scoping logic in place to distinguish what a "failed" vs "successful" (??!) office would be.

Comment: @TomLord i have a worker defined and I am running a job and I want to store the office ids for which the job failed.

Comment: @TomLord **uninitialized constant Reminder::Failedoffice** I am still getting the error

Comment: `has_and_belongs_to_many :failed_offices, class_name: "Office"` but I guess, in `Office` model, you will have to add the line `has_and_belongs_to_many :reminders, as: :failed_offices`. Not sure but you can try.